# Custom web part with deleted list

Tags: 2007, web-part, list

I have a Web Part which links to a list.

I'm not sure if this is the standard, but the developers have hard linked the list to the web part so that this particular list is set as a default of sorts. However, I deleted the list because it was dummy content.

When I click on "open the tool pane" to configure the Web Part and select another list I get the error

> COMException (0x81020026): List does not exist
>
> The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

Considering I can't restore the item from the recycling bin as it is no longer there, is there still a way around this?

Note the site is locked down so I can't edit the Web Part myself in an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the error try exporting the web part and opened it in notepad.
There will be an entry:

```
<property name="ListGuid" type="string">280569DE-6723-4840-BF61-75F02E4226DC</property>
```

Deleted this line, as there is another line which specifies the List name:

```
<property name="ListName" type="string">LIST NAME</property>
```

The same situation can occur with the DataView Web Parts also and the solution is:

1) Export the web part

2) Edit it in notepad

3) Replace the list GUID (after ListID) with the name of the list

4) Replace all occurances of "ListID" with "ListName"

Comment: How do I import it back into the site once I have made the changes above?

Comment: Also, the words "GUID" or the actual GUID e.g. "280569DE-6723-4840-BF61-75F02E4226DC" only appear on that one line in the document. I'm confused at what I should be replacing and I also don't know what you mean by replace with "Column names"?

Comment: With FilterField1 it shows like this: <property name="FilterField1" type="string" /> no GUID or ProductTypeKey

Comment: what kind of Web part is it? Is it CQWP or Dataview Web part?

Comment: Here is the way to import and export web part http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2009/01/08/how-to-export-amp-import-web-parts-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: You can export the CQWP and remove the old list's GUID references and try importing the Web part again. Hopefully, this will resolve the issue.

Comment: This seems to import the web part only to the specific page. Is it possible to rewrite the web part in the collection?

Comment: No there is no way to do it and either you have to do it manually (page by page basis) or write a code which performs this operation manually.